# Running EF migrations in Docker container with running application

Tags: entity-framework, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to configure an ASP.NET Core project to run inside a Docker container.

It works well and everything is OK. The problem is that when I want to execute the new migrations that I have created I get an error stating that my **.csproj** file is used by another process and is locked. That leads to failure in my attempt to update the database. It must be locked by the **dotnet watch run** command that is my entry point in the Dockerfile.

One solution that I am thinking about is to create a separate project with CLI application that runs the migrations when I run it. But that means that I need separate project for every command that I might need to use and doesn't sound very well.

In all tutorials that I found is shown to run the migrations on project startup but I feel like this is a little dangerous especially in a production environment. How do you handle EF migrations in Docker containers?

Here is my Dockerfile that I use for development so that I can have hot reloading on file change. I mount my code volume within a docker-compose.yml file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1

ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER 1

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT dotnet watch run --urls=http://+:5000
```

Comment: Why you're running `dotnet watch` in Docker?

Comment: It is for development purposes. I want to run it in Docker while developing the application and then I will have a separate Dockerfile for production.

Comment: Currently, I don't think there is a recommendation available on how to run the migration on Docker containers. Since you're using this for development purposes, why don't you run migrations from code? And I don't think running migrations in docker container is the right way to do things.

Comment: Late to the party! Could you find any solution for this?